# Linking libstdc++ statically on Mac OS X

Tags: static, g++, libstdc++

I want to link libstdc++ statically on Mac OS X 10.8.4 so that the binary can be used in other systems.

I found some discussion for linux. I'm wondering what would the instructions for Mac OS X.

http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/

I have the following GCC.

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the gcc 4.2.1 that you have supports this method, but here's what worked for me in a similar situation on OS X 10.9:

- upgrade to the latest Xcode command line tools (I have 5.0.1.0.1.1382131676)
- install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)
- `brew tap versions`
- `brew install gcc48`
- then configure/build your software with:

  `CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 LDFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"`

The static flags were available for me in this gcc 4.8 build by Homebrew, and the resulting executables looked like:

```
$ otool -L seqdb-compress
seqdb-compress:
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

with no libgcc or libstdc++ dynamic libs. I haven't yet tested these executables out on a different OS X system but will update this post if they don't work for any reason.

Comment: Does not work with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2). `clang: error: unsupported option '-static-libgcc'`. When this is removed: `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++'`